# dynamically setting button text of different HTML page simultaneously while loading it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two HTML pages, where i load page two within page one using jquery. i want to dynamically set a button text that exists within page two as i am loading it.

code:

```
                $("#SerachForTruckTD").load("SearchBox.html");

                if(parsedOBJ.KIOSKTYPE == "THRU"){

                    $('#submitTruckPass').val('name1');
                    }
                    else if(parsedOBJ.KIOSKTYPE == "EX"){
                    $('#submitTruckPass').val('name 2');
                    }
```

i think the issue here is that when the code reach the point where it wants to set the button text, the page is not loaded yet. because setting a timeout before setting the button text as follows works fine:

```
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if(parsedOBJ.KIOSKTYPE == "THRU"){

                    $('#submitTruckPass').val('name1');
                    }
                    else if(parsedOBJ.KIOSKTYPE == "EX"){
                    $('#submitTruckPass').val('name2 ');
                    } 

                }, 1000);
```

but the idea is that i want to set the button text simultaneously while loading the page, not after one second. is there a solution for this?

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this might be to fetch the file with AJAX, do the replacement, and then add it:

```
$.ajax({url: "SearchBox.html", success: function(result){
 var value;
 if(parsedOBJ.KIOSKTYPE == "THRU"){
  value = "name1"
 }else if(parsedOBJ.KIOSKTYPE == "EX"){
  value = "name 2"
 };
 var insert = $(result).find("#submitTruckPass").val(value);
 $("#SearchForTruckTD").append(insert);
}});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. it does work simultaneously with the ajax, but it doesn't set the text for the required button rather establish a new button with same functionality of the original one which is with id : "submitTruckPass"

Comment: just replaced last two lines with : $('#submitTruckPass').val(value); no need for .find() and .append() functions.